# Do all closed positive currents lift to a resolution?

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Consider a normal complex analytic space $X$ and a projective birational resolution $f:Y\rightarrow X$. Let $T$ be a closed positive current of bi-dimension $(p,p)$ on $X$. Is there always a closed positive current $S$ on $Y$ such that $f_*S=T$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is no.

If I am reading the article below by Méo correctly, he shows that if
$\pi : Y \to X$ is the blowup of the polydisc $X=D^m$ along $Z := \{ z_1 = \dots = z_k = 0 \}$, and if $k \leq p \leq n-2$, then there exists a closed positive $(p,p)$-current $T$ on $X$ such that $T' := \pi^* (T|_{X\setminus Z})$ does not have locally finite mass near $\pi^{-1}(Z)$. If such $S$ exists, then since $\pi$ is a biholomorphism on $Y' := \pi^{-1}(X\setminus Z)$, one would have $S|_{Y'} = T'$, which would thus have locally finite mass.

**Reference**

Michel Méo, "[Image inverse d'un courant positif fermé par une application analytique surjective](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k9800442g/f35.item)", C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. I Math. 322 (1996), no. 12, 1141–1144, [MR1396655](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1396655), [Zbl 0858.32012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0858.32012).

Comment: Tack, Richard! That's indeed what I'm looking for.